# Flutter: does scrollController.position.isScrollingNotifier need to remove listener on dispose? Why's it crashing my app?

Tags: flutter, dart, dispose

I am able to demonstrate my issue with this simple code below.

Basically, I am adding listener to both the `ScrollController` and `scrollController.position.isScrollingNotifier` in the init. The `scrollController.position.isScrollingNotifier` allows me to listen for scrolling start and stopped events. It works fine.

Now when I tap a list tile, it navigates to a new screen (same widget as previous).

However, when I navigate back to the previous screen, the app crashes with error:

```
_AssertionError ('package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_controller.dart': Failed assertion: line 107 pos 12: '_positions.isNotEmpty': ScrollController not attached to any scroll views.)
```

The crash is occurring at the `removeListener` line in the `dispose`:

`scrollController.position.isScrollingNotifier.removeListener(handleScrollStartStop);`

If I comment this line out, then the app works fine.

I thought I am supposed to remove listeners in dispose if I added them? Then why the crash?

What am I doing wrong?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(
        viewNumber: 0,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.viewNumber});
  final int viewNumber;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  late ScrollController scrollController = ScrollController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    print("initState GODVC");
    super.initState();

    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
      scrollController.addListener(handleScrolled);
      scrollController.position.isScrollingNotifier.addListener(handleScrollStartStop);
    });
  }

  void handleScrollStartStop() {
    // print("handleScrollStartStop");
    if (!scrollController.position.isScrollingNotifier.value) {
      print('Scroll stopped');
    } else {
      print('Scroll started');
    }
  }

  void handleScrolled() {
    print("handleScrolled: $mounted, ${scrollController.offset}");
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    print("dispose");
    scrollController.position.isScrollingNotifier.removeListener(handleScrollStartStop);
    print("disposed GODVC 2");
    scrollController.removeListener(handleScrolled);
    print("disposed GODVC 3");
    scrollController.dispose();
    print("disposed GODVC 4");
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("${widget.viewNumber}"),
        leading: Navigator.canPop(context)
            ? MaterialButton(
                padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                onPressed: () {
                  if (Navigator.canPop(context)) {
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  }
                },
                child: const Icon(
                  Icons.chevron_left,
                  size: 45,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              )
            : null,
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        controller: scrollController,
        itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
          return ListTile(
            title: Text("$index. Something"),
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.of(context).push(
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => MyHomePage(
                    viewNumber: widget.viewNumber + 1,
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          );
        }),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: "I thought I am supposed to remove listeners in dispose if I added them?" - see https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/b8f7f1f9869bb2d116aa6a70dbeac61000b52849/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/scroll_controller.dart#L197

Comment: @pskink is the `for (final ScrollPosition position in _positions) {
      position.removeListener(notifyListeners);
    }` also removing the listener for `isScrollingNotifier` automatically? So I don't need to remove it myself?

Comment: check `ScrollPosition.dispose()` method (one line above `super.dispose()` is called)